# Opening Telnet Sessions to Cisco Device

Tags: c#, ssh, telnet

I need to establish a telnet session with a Cisco device and send commands depending on the device reply.

I tried:

Headers:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

Code:

```
TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection("gobelijn", 23);
Telnet t = new Telnet();
```

Both doesn't work!

I get these errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'TelnetConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'Telnet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm totally lost here and need support.

Also, if there is a simple way to connect using SSH not Telnet, kindly provide.

***UPDATE***

I've followed what Andreas stated down, but now I'm getting an error:

```
System.Exception: Failed to connect : no login prompt
at ciscoManager.TelnetConnection.Login(String Username, String Password, Int32 LoginTimeOutMs)
at ciscoManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

In my code, I'm trying to send an "Enter" Key press using `\r\n` and tried also `\n` with no joy!

NEED HELP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember there is no `TelnetConnection` or `Telnet` class in `System.Net` nor `System.Net.Sockets`.

There are however a few open source projects providing the missing pieces:

For Telnet:
http://telnetexpect.codeplex.com

For SSH:
http://sshnet.codeplex.com 🍺 https://nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/

or
http://granados.sourceforge.net

*Edit:*
You most likely found this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library), but did not add the needed dependencies to your project.

Comment: I found the mentioned tutorial, but what are the dependencies you are talking about? Can you guide me?

Comment: There is a file `TelnetInterface.cs` in the download on code project. You have to include this file into your Visual Studio project. Instead of doing this, I personally would go with one of the more mature apis on codeplex.

Comment: I've added the file as you suggested .. But still can't connect!! Now I'm trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 2001 I get an output but nothing is sent to the device

Comment: As I already stated, you should not use the code in the tutorial as it lacks quality, maintainability and most likely works only on the happy path. Anyway, at least you should haven gotten a connection otherwise an NullPointerException would have thrown. The code expects an `:` as a sign for the login prompt this is not returned by your connection.